# Закрыть интерактивное окно matplotlib в jupyter по кнопке прерывания

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Необходимо написать код **в jupyter notebook**, который бы в реальном времени выводил график по данным, считываемым с внешних источников (условно осциллограф). **Бэкенд matplotlib - qt5**.
С самой программой проблем нет, однако выявилась следующая неприятная особенность библиотеки matplotlib в юпитере:
Если прервать весь процесс в ноутбуке - окно графика не закрывается
[image: Прерывание процесса]

***При том, если тот же код перенести в обычный .py файл - все работает отлично и при прерывании процесса все окна закрываются***

Для примера приведу простую конструкцию:

```
%matplotlib qt5
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.show()
```

При выполнении в юпитере открывается всплывающее окно с пустым графиком, но если остановить процесс - оно не закрывается.
Хотел бы поинтересоваться, как сделать так, чтобы при прерывании в юпитере все окна закрывались?

Comment: Я вот как-то сомневаюсь, что юпитер даст вам возможность управлять фигурой по событию останова скрипта, но может быть эта ссылка вам как-то поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101046/a-blocking-interactive-plot-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и должно быть.

Кнопка "Квадрат" не останавливает процесс, а посылает в процесс сообщение "прервать выполнение текущей ячейки". В вашем случае после `plt.show()` ячейка считается выполненой, поэтому "Квадрат" игнорируется.

Чтобы закрыть все открытые окна, нужно выполнить в новой ячейке код `plt.close('all')`.

Если же вы хотите имитировать блокирующий вызов графического окна, чтобы ячейка была активной до его закрытия, то можно сделать вот так:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.show()

try:
    # Пока есть активные рисунки
    while len(plt.get_fignums()) > 0:
        # передавать управление в графический event loop
        # Если это не делать, ничего не будет нарисовано
        plt.pause(0.1)
except:
    # При нажатии на черный квадрат в python event loop вбрасывается KeyboardInterrupt
    # закрыть все активные окна
    plt.close('all')
```

Как это работает.

Чтобы кнопка "Квадрат" сработала, нужно, чтобы ячейка была активной. Для этого нужно в конце ячейки добавить (бесконечный) цикл. По нажатию кнопки "Квадрат" в пайтоновский event loop будет вброшено прерывание `KeyboardInterrupt`. Нужно поймать это прерывание и закрыть все текущие окна.

Окошко рисуется в другом event loop, в котором `KeyboardInterrupt` не видно. Поэтому нужно внутри цикла передавать управление в графический event loop только на время. Это делается функцией [`pyplot.pause`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause).

Совсем бесконечный цикл не заметит закрытия окна. Поэтому нужно добавить условие завершения цикла когда все окна закрыты. Функция [`pyplot.get_fignums`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.get_fignums.html#matplotlib.pyplot.get_fignums) возвращает список номеров активных окон (figures). Когда пользователь закроет все окна, эта функция вернёт пустой список. Тогда можно завершить цикл и выполнение ячейки.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!! Вы - талант!